# Why Airflow Worker Tries to connect to local MYSQL server rather than taking from airflow config

Tags: airflow

When I start a airflow worker with some queue It throws the below Error.

I have configured db details in airflow config. but not sure why it tries to connect to local mysql server

```
[2018-10-29 18:59:32,012: ERROR/MainProcess] Pool callback raised exception: OperationalError('(_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2002, "Can\'t connect to local MySQL server through socket \'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock\' (2)")',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1747, in safe_apply_callback
    fun(*args, **kwargs)
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 393, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)")
```

Comment: In airflow.cfg did you set both `sql_alchemy_conn` and `result_backend`?

Comment: What's in the `billiard.pool` module?

Comment: guys, regretting myself. I was failed to install pip install apache-airflow[mysql]. thanks for your contribution guys.